# Bibliography error with revtex4 when language included with @book

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

When I try to compile a Latex document citing the following entry in a .bib:

```
@book{a_book,
    title = {A Book},
    publisher = {Book Publisher},
    author = {Fist, Last},
    year = {2015},
    language = {en},
}
```

I get the following two errors:

```
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.
Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the language english yet.
```

Everything is fine when I remove `language = {en}` from my BibTex entry. 
However, this line is included without error on `@article` entries.

What's going on? Why does including this line cause an error only with `@book` entries?

**Version Info:**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
```

**Test Files:**

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
This is an article. \cite{an_article}.

This is a book \cite{a_book}.   

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

*test.bib*

```
@book{a_book,
 title = {A Book},
 publisher = {Book Publisher},
 author = {Last, First},
 year = {2015},
 language = {en},
}

@article{an_article,
 title = {An Article},
 volume = {1},
 number = {1},
 journal = {Journal},
 author = {Last, First},
 year = {2015},
 pages = {1-10},
 language = {en},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You should call package `babel` with option `english` and change `language={en}` in the bib entries to  `language={english}`.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a `language` field in a bib entry, you need to load `babel` with the appropriate language options for all the languages you need. The last one specified will be the default.

However, `language={en}` will result in `\selectlanguage{en}` in the `.bbl` file, which `babel` doesn't understand. Nonetheless, we can stretch a bit `babel` and make it use language aliases. It would be a good feature for `babel`, in my opinion, and it's not really so difficult to implement.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a_book,
 title = {A Book},
 publisher = {Book Publisher},
 author = {Last, First},
 year = {2015},
 language = {en},
}

@article{an_article,
 title = {An Article},
 volume = {1},
 number = {1},
 journal = {Journal},
 author = {Last, First},
 year = {2015},
 pages = {1-10},
 language = {en},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
% A change to a babel macro
\def\bbl@set@language#1{%
  \edef\languagename{%
    \ifnum\escapechar=\expandafter`\string#1\@empty
    \else\string#1\@empty\fi}%
  %%%% ADDITION
  \@ifundefined{babel@language@alias@\languagename}{}{%
    \edef\languagename{\@nameuse{babel@language@alias@\languagename}}%
  }%
  %%%% END ADDITION
  \select@language{\languagename}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname date\languagename\endcsname\relax\else
    \if@filesw
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\select@language{\languagename}}%
      \bbl@for\bbl@tempa\BabelContentsFiles{%
        \addtocontents{\bbl@tempa}{\xstring\select@language{\languagename}}}%
      \bbl@usehooks{write}{}%
    \fi
  \fi}
% The user interface
\newcommand{\DeclareLanguageAlias}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{babel@language@alias@#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareLanguageAlias{en}{english}

\begin{document}
This is an article. \cite{an_article}.

This is a book \cite{a_book}.   

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]